# mosync c++ or javascript

Tags: mosync

Is the performance of apps developed in mosync same c++ same as those developed with html5 and javascript.
What are the pros and cons of using c++ or using javascript.

Regards,

Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

in short answer "No"!

When you are using the c++, you actually work with CPU (or at least Operating System), but if you write your programs with "HTML", an extra layer has been added.
The browser(Webkit in android and Iphone) interpret html/js and specially in android there is an obvious reduction in speed (its better on android 4.x but mosync doesn't support it by now )!

But designing User Interface in HTML is easy! and for simple applications its worth it IMO!